# Persistent encoding job

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Can I have persistent encoding job in Azure?

I want to upload video stream into page blob and encode it on the fly when new portion of data is available. 
Can it be done with azure or I need 3rd party solution like wowza?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but... I'd suggest taking a look at the details of [Windows Azure Media Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/media-services/). There's a [tuturial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/) which includes details on topics such as [encoding](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/encode-an-asset/) and [content streaming](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/deliver-streaming-content/). Not sure if this covers all of your app-specific use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the comments of David Makogon - no, currently you cannot achieve your goal. The current state of Azure Media Services works only for Video-On-Demand. What you need is more like a live streaming.

For live streaming you can use [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media). You can install IIS Media Services along with the [Transform Manager Extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/transform-manager). To almost fully achieve your goal. And you can do this on a Windows Server image of [Azure Virtual Machine](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/).

To achieve elasticity and scalability however will not be an easy task.

To conclude - the current state of all Azure services is not 100% suitable for your scenario. And it does not provide out-of-the-box solution for your need. If you find a 3rd party provider that suits your needs **today**, then just go ahead and test/use it.